# Receiving null from getParcelableExtra()

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin

I have a class category and i pass into the extra, the category clicked.
this worked in 6 screens but in the last one I'm receiving null

the activity where i put the extra

```
adapter.setOnItemClickListener { item, view ->

                    val categories = item as Categories
                    val intent = Intent(view.context, LearningFirstLibras::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra(CATEGORY_KEY, categories.category)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
```

the category

```
@Parcelize
class Category(
               val name: String,
               val imageURL: String,
               val real_name: String,
               val object_1_screen_libras_image: String,
               val object_1_screen_libras_text: String,
               val object_2_screen_libras_text: String,
               val object_2_screen_libras_image: String,
               val object_3_screen_libras_text: String,
               val object_3_screen_libras_image: String,
               val object_1_screen_asl_text: String,
               val object_1_screen_asl_image: String,
               val object_2_screen_asl_text: String,
               val object_2_screen_asl_image: String,
               val object_3_screen_asl_text: String,
               val object_3_screen_asl_image: String,
               val question: String,
               val answer: String,
               val alternative_1: String,
               val alternative_2: String,
               val alternative_3: String,
               val alternative_4: String
                ) : Parcelable {
    constructor() : this("", "", "", "", "",
            "","","","",
            "","","","",
            "","","","","","",
            "","")
}
```

the activity where i got null

```
class Quiz : AppCompatActivity() {

    var categoryF:Category = Category()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz)

        categoryF = intent.getParcelableExtra(NewWordsActivity.CATEGORY_KEY)
```

Comment: No need to create  constructor() : this("", "", "", "", "",
            "","","","",
            "","","","",
            "","","","","","",
            "","")

Comment: Make sure categories.category is not null , try debug your code.

Comment: You're launching `LearningFirstLibras` activity but reading the value in `Quiz` activity?

Comment: i used logs to get the categories.category and 2 values inside the categories.category
i got the values:

2019-05-21 09:37:33.436 5433-5433/com.educator.dualsignal D/teste: com.educator.dualsignal.models.Category@a870587 /


2019-05-21 09:38:43.790 5622-5622/com.educator.dualsignal D/teste: foods_1 /
2019-05-21 09:38:43.792 5622-5622/com.educator.dualsignal D/teste: alternativa_1

Comment: You should be starting `Quiz` instead of `LearningFirstLibras`, probably.

Answer (score 0):

**Try it**

**Sending the Parcelable Using Bundle**

```
val intent = Intent(this, ProfilePage::class.java)
var bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putParcelable(CATEGORY_KEY, categories.category)
intent.putExtra("myBundle",bundle)
startActivity(intent)
```

**Recovering Parcelable**

```
val bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("myBundle")
var categoryF = bundle.getParcelable<Category>(NewWordsActivity.CATEGORY_KEY) as Category
```

Comment: What's the motivation behind this answer? How should it solve the problem? How is wrapping it into another bundle different to what `.putExtra()` does? Can you elaborate, please?

Comment: Motive is Vinicius Barros want to parse data from one to another so i was used in my code pass parcelable data using bundle so i was share it. may be it helped...

Comment: I understand that, but my point is that you didn't provide an explanation for why your provided solution would/should work. In my opinion, adding another layer (provided by the `Bundle` in your code) doesn't solve the problem.